# Zoom controls are both zoomIn my TextView, instead of one of them zoomOut

Tags: android, textview, zooming, font-size

//the zoomIn method. works perfectly

```
    zoom.setOnZoomInClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    float x = aboutTextView.getTextSize();

    aboutTextView.setTextSize((float) (x+1));
}
    });
```

//the zooOut method. also doing zoomIn in runtime...

```
    zoom.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    float x = aboutTextView.getTextSize();

    aboutTextView.setTextSize((float) (x-1));
}
    });
```

Comment: Yes, i'll edit my tags...